# Memgraph very slow query when using neo4j java driver

Tags: java, memgraph

My setup:

1.) memgraph in a docker image locally with 500k nodes inserted

2.) I have a query with in clause in java using neo4j driver like

```
MATCH (n:SomeNode) where n.compoundKey in $ids RETURN n
```

this query for lets say 180 ids is executing 22sec ins java but if i execute the query  in the memgraph lab it takes 5ms

Is there something specific with the java driver that I need to take care of?

the java code look like this

```
public List<Noad> getByKeys(Collection<String> keys) {
    try (Session session = driver.session()) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("ids", keys);
        final String query = """
                MATCH (n:SomeNode)
                WHERE n.compoundKey IN $ids
                RETURN n
                """;
        Result result = session.run(query, params);
        .......
    }
}
```

Using

neo4j driver

```
org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:5.13.0
```

Java 21

Memgraph 2.11.0 running locally in a docker

settings for the driver inside quarkus app

```
   neo4j:
    pool:
      max-connection-pool-size: 50
      log-leaked-sessions: true
    uri: bolt://localhost:7687
```

Comment: Hi @simonC, can you maybe share what version of Memgraph and Java driver you are using in this case? I guess both Lab and Java driver are querying the same instance?

Comment: @AnteJavor I have updated the question with the versions we are using ... we are using bolt protocol bolt://localhost:7687

Comment: Hi @simonC, is "MATCH (o:Noad)" intentional? Do you maybe have a typo in this query? 
Should it be MATCH (o:Node)?

Comment: @AnteJavor no it is a typo

Comment: If that is a typo, and the lab query is correct using: MATCH (o:Node) you are probably not utilizing an index there, on label + property from the driver side. Can you check that?

Comment: @AnteJavor no I am using the sam query ... copy paste in the lab ... I have changed the query using WITH and UNWIND to pass the ids and it is working much faster ... but if I use the mentioned query it is very slow

Comment: Ok, I ran a small test of this and didn't experience the issue you mentioned.  Will spend some time and try to replicate it. Will keep you posted here.

Comment: I think I have managed to find the issue with this. I have noticed that closing a session after the query took 6 seconds on Memgraph 2.12. Query execution was still quite fast in the milliseconds range. 

Can you measure the time passed for opening and closing a session + execution of a query? 

Here is what I did: https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/1450

Comment: but with WITH and UNWIND it works much faster ... why would the session be the cause?

Comment: Take a look at the sample code that is linked to the issue (https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/1450) query execution is very fast, and session close is much slower, it took 6 seconds at some point on 2.11. 

You mentioned that the query works very fast with Lab. Lab does not use Java driver, and if query + dataset is the same in Lab and your Java code, then it is probably related to the driver. 

Sessions seems like possible cause. 

Have you tried measuring passed time for opening and closing sessions + execution?

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I think this is related to potentially slow session closing with Neo4j driver, not actual query execution: https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/1450